# update values in IQueryable doesn't save to database

Tags: c#, linq, gridview, iqueryable

I am trying to update values that I use `IQueryable` to search my linq to classes datacontext, why I am trying is:

```
var records=  dinner.GetRecords(id).WHERE(d=>d.Year == Yearpassed).AsEnumerable()//returns IQUERYABLE<t>
foreach( var record in records)
{
   record.Year='2000'
}
dinner.Save(); //this just does a db.SubmitChanges()
```

Then I do another query of the data and bind it to the gridview and the record data is the same

```
var records=  dinner.GetRecords(id);
gridview1.DataSource =records;
gridview1.DataBind();

public IQueryable<dinners> GetRecords(string id)
{
     return from dinner in db.dinners
        where dinner.id =id
        select dinner
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not modifying the original collection. Calling AsEnumarable is creating a new collection and thus you are changing a list of properties that the original data context cannot see.

Try it like this...

```
foreach( var record in dinner.GetRecords(id).Where(d=>d.Year == Yearpassed))
{
   record.Year='2000';
}
dinner.Save();
```

Essentially, I have just remove the AsEnumarble() part

If this doesn't work then I suspect we should need to see the code in your GetRecords() method

Comment: @Jake why are you calling AsEnumerable()?

Comment: that doesnt do it. I will post what getRecord does, but all it is a linq query of the passed id

Comment: @Jake: Hold on, could the single = have anything to do with it? I have changed to == in my code

Comment: no sorry that was a typo in my code. I have == in my actual code, but will make the change in post

Comment: @Jake, so is your GetRecords just returning one record? and is that record being removed by the where clause? Add a breakpoint in your foreach loop and see what gets changed. Also, see my edit

Comment: no it returns multiple records, when debugging it shows that it goes through the foreach loop but and changes the value on exit, but doesnt show after changes are submitted

Comment: its a double primary key/composite, so the id returns multiple records, the year and the id is what makes the record unique

Comment: Do the changes get pushed to the database? perhaps this is a databind issue

Comment: no it doesn't get pushed to the database, thats the problem. because even if I come back to the page it still has the old data

Comment: I dont think I can help from your code then. This seems very strange and given that you say debugging shows the values are changing and you Save() method only call db.SubmitChanges(); then I would be expecting it to work

Comment: I think it has to do with SubmitChanges, let me take some more look into it and Ill get back with you

Comment: AsEnumerable() doesn't change the types. It are the entities that are tracked by the TrackingManager (or not).

Comment: Thanks I fixed it, it was basically in my DB, that no primary key was set because it was using the old linq to sql classes